# Typesetting "LaTeX" in LaTeX

Tags: macros

There seems to be a macro for typesetting the acronym `LaTeX`, but I cannot think of manual to look it up or search term that would return relevant results.

How can I typeset the word `LaTeX` as it usually appears in `LaTeX` documentation - with the vertically staggered letters?

I know this is going to be a duplicate, but cannot help it :(

Comment: Simply use `\LaTeX{}` or `\LaTeX2e{}` according to what you need.

Comment: That's an answer!

Comment: Is not an answer, it's too short and simple for that.

Comment: Oh, and where are such macros documented?

Comment: @Aradnix `\LaTeXe` not `\LaTeX2e` You can't have digits in macro names.

Comment: Well in many places, this specific macro you can find it easily in the web, you can make a search like this: [how to typeset the latex logo on latex](https://www.google.com.mx/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+typeset+the+latex+logo+on+latex&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=2Lj3U77iMazI8gfhvYBo) I have documentation about it, let me see...

@DavidCarlisle you're right, my fault.

Comment: @ajeh `texdoc usrguide` (or simply see `userguide.pdf` which is part of the core base latex distribution documents these macros.

Comment: @ajeh This document: [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) can be useful also.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not even by changing catcodes? `;-)`

Comment: @1010011010 -- but you'd have to change the catcode back immediately after the definition, and possibly also every time you used the command, otherwise any other `2` would get fouled up, especially if you make the definition without resetting the catcode before defining a new command with two arguments.  that's just plain too much work.